# JpaRepository, @Transaction, and repository.saveAndFlush

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm taking my first crack at the Service/Repository approach and am running into an issue. Essentially what I want to do in my Service is persist my entity and then use its ID in the same Service method.

Originally I was going to use @GeneratedValue and Sequences but gave up and settled on manually flushing the entity and grabbing the ID , which I thought would be easier.

My Repository is an Interface using Spring Data, so it has support for manual flushes. As I understand it, it also is annotated with @Transactional. My Service method is also annotated with @Transactional.

What I've found is that the entity is only persisted upon return of the Service method, even when I flush immediately after saving the entity (or use saveAndFlush). I thought that flushing would force the DB changes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring-data-jpa return the "future" entity (i.e. with id) when you call save, so:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo = this.fooRepository.save(foo); // also work on Collections
this.fooRepository.flush();
// use foo.getId();
```

Answer (score 3):

call saveAndFlush method will work!

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo = this.fooRepository.saveAndFlush(foo); 
// use foo.getId();
```