# Why is ID not set in entity returned from spring-data-jpa save

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple entity.  I'm using spring-data-jpa version 1.2.0.RELEASE and eclipselink 2.4.1.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="platform")
public class Platform {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, updatable=false, insertable=true)
    private Long id;
    // etc.
}
```

I want to save it. My repository looks like

```
public interface PlatformRepository extends JpaRepository<Platform, Long> {

    Platform findByName( String name );
}
```

My Controller is very simple with this method

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
public Platform post( Platform platform ) {
    Platform result = platformDao.saveAndFlush(platform);
    return result;
}
```

And the response from that method is

```
{"platform":{"id":null,"name":"Test1"}}
```

Select * from platform shows that Test1 has an ID of 6.  The table is defined as:

```
create table platform(
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(128) not null);
```

I expect the ID to be set after the save, but it isn't. They're not expecting me to do a lookup immediately after writing the entity, right?

Comment: Just a guess: try to change `id` from `Long` to `int` and `insertable=true` to `false`. Also, [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122489/jparepository-transaction-and-repository-saveandflush) might be relevant.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have not specified that the ID was autogenerated by the database in your mapping. Add

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

to your ID field. Without it, JPA doesn't know that it must execute a select statement after insertion in order to get the generated ID from the database.

Comment: Duh...I knew that. I'll accept this as soon as I validate it.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but even after using the       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
the problem persists. Any other workaround?